# Using statement and the IDisposable interface

Tags: c#, vb.net

Is it true that the variables declared within a using statement are disposed together because they are in the scope of the using block?

Do I need to do:

```
using (SomeIdisposableImplementation foo = new SomeIdisposableImplementation())
{
    using(SomeIdisposableImplementation2 bar = new SomeIdisposableImplementation2())
    {

    }
}
```

or will this be enough and is "bar" disposed together with "foo"?

```
using (SomeIdisposableImplementation foo = new SomeIdisposableImplementation())
{
    SomeIdisposableImplementation2 bar = new SomeIdisposableImplementation2();
}
```

Comment: have you missed `=` in `SomeIdisposableImplementation2`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> or will this be enough and is "bar" disposed together with "foo"?

No, bar will not be disposed.

`using` statement translates into `try-finally` block, so even if an exception occurs the `finally` block ensures the call to `Dispose` method.

Following

```
using (SomeIdisposableImplementation foo = new SomeIdisposableImplementation())
{
    SomeIdisposableImplementation2 bar = new SomeIdisposableImplementation2();
}
```

Translates into

```
{
    SomeIdisposableImplementation foo;
    try
    {
        foo = new SomeIdisposableImplementation();
        SomeIdisposableImplementation2 bar = new SomeIdisposableImplementation2();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (foo != null)
            foo.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Leaving `bar` un-disposed.

Answer (score 4):

To get them both disposed with the using statement you do not have to nest them however you can write this

```
using (SomeIdisposableImplementation foo = new SomeIdisposableImplementation())
{
    using(SomeIdisposableImplementation2 bar = new SomeIdisposableImplementation2())
    {

    }
}
```

as

```
using (SomeIdisposableImplementation foo = new SomeIdisposableImplementation())
using(SomeIdisposableImplementation2 bar = new SomeIdisposableImplementation2())
{


}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the second version bar will just go out of scope but will not be disposed. But you can put both foo and bar into the same using command:

```
using (SomeIdisposableImplementation foo = new SomeIdisposableImplementation(), SomeIdisposableImplementation2 bar = new SomeIdisposableImplementation2())
{
    // use foo and bar
}
```

you can also just put the variables into the using command:

```
SomeIdisposableImplementation foo = new SomeIdisposableImplementation();
SomeIdisposableImplementation2 bar = new SomeIdisposableImplementation2();
using (foo, bar)
{
    // use foo and bar
}
```

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is correct. The rest is wrong.

Comment: Your edited second option Roland is incorrect. If `bar = new SomeIdisposableImplementation2()` throws an exception, or a threaded exception occurs before entering the `using` block `foo` (and `bar`) will never be disposed.

Comment: The correct syntax is either `using(S1 foo = new S1()) using (S2 bar = new S2()) { ... }`  or, if `foo` and `bar` are the same type, `using(S1 foo = new S1(), bar = new S1()) { ... }`.  It would be nice if `using(S1 foo = new S1(); S2 bar = new S2()) { ... } ` were legal, but it is not.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: `using` is not robust in the face of thread abort exceptions at all.  Consider: `S1 foo = null; try { foo = new S1(); ... } finally { if (foo != null) foo.Dispose(); }`.  Now suppose the thread abort exception is thrown during the constructor of `S1`, but *after* the constructor has created the unmanaged resource. `foo` will never be assigned, and so it will still be null in the `finally`.  The only way the resource can be released here is in the finalizer. This is why you need to always write finalizers to be robust in the face of a partially constructed object.

Comment: @EricLippert You are right, it's only possible when both are the same type, i mixed it up. Sorry

Comment: Well sure Eric, but that's part of implementing good disposable/unmanaged types (just as you point out). I was merely pointing out a couple reasons why Roland's second example would fail. EDIT: Ahh, on second read I can see how my comment can suggest that the `using` block will properly manage this, not what I meant. :)

Comment: @KeesdeWit first part is wrong, second part can be used if the constructor of SomeIdisposableImplementation2 will not throw an exception, but is still not best practice, as foo and bar are still in scope after the using block.

Comment: @KeesdeWit: The first sentence is correct. The rest of it is wrong.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: Right, my point is that though it is correct to note that the code shown here is not robust in the face of a thread abort exception, that is not in of itself a motivation to use the `using` statement, because the `using` statement isn't robust against thread aborts either. In general I really care very little about cleaning up resources in the exceptional scenario because *it is exceptional*. You simply can't clean up resources in all exceptional scenarios, and by definition they are exceptional; worry instead about always cleaning up in typical scenarios.